# Knowing if both row exists and there's a value (or null) with asyncpg

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

I want to provide descriptive error/information messages when configuring a news feed on one of my Discord bots:

- One for when there's no feed configured (Row doesn't exist.)
- One for when a specific column has a NULL value.

While this is simple to do with two queries, I want to simplify this to one query and if possible simple and I came up with one approach: Use `fetchrow` which will return a `Record` object. This meets my two conditions, if there's no row in the database I will get `None` as a result but if there's a row I will get the `Record` object with the column I selected, which will or won't be `NULL`. For example:

```
update = await self.bot.database.fetchrow('UPDATE NewsFeed SET role_id = NULL '
                                          'WHERE guild_id = $1 AND key = $2 '
                                          'RETURNING role_id', ctx.guild.id, key)
```

Which I can just do `if not update` to check whether the `Record` exists and then `if not update["role_id"]` to check if the `role_id` column is `NULL`.

My question is: Is there a different/simpler approach for this or this is good to go?